# Gvim overwriting font from nord

Tags: vim

I would like to have my font to be from the [Nord Color Theme](https://github.com/arcticicestudio/nord) as seen in [here](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/). I should say I am on linux ubuntu. Here is my .vimrc

[image]

[image]

This seems to change the color scheme of gVim, but it doesn't change the font :

[image]

Does anybody have any ideas how to get the nord font style in gVim?

Comment: Vim colorschemes, Nord included, generally don't define fonts. If you want a specific font in GVim, see `:help 'guifont'`.